# find etags not working right from ".txt" file

Tags: symbols, syntax, etags

I use `etags` to find functions in my C code and everything works fine when I'm in a `.c` (or `.h`) file.

If I use the `find-tag` key (`M-.`) when the buffer is a different type of file (`.txt`) the tag search parses the string under the cursor differently. If I'm on a C function name in the `.txt` file then it doesn't handle underscores in the name (for example if I'm on `UI_ModuleTask` it searches for `UI` or `ModuleTask` depending on which character the cursor is on).

I'm assuming there's some logic that automatically parses tag names based on the buffer's file type, but I've been unable to determine where in the Elisp that is happening.

Comment: is `M-.` `find-tag` or `xref-find-definintions`? try the opposite of whatever it's bound to.

Comment: That as a good thought to try both of those, but I'm getting the same result either way. Looking into it more, 'xref-find-defininitions' (which is what M-. normally calls on my setup) doesn't directly handle parsing the identifier under the cursor. The major mode of the buffer is supposed to supply 'xref-backend-functions', which handle that sort of thing in a language-specific way. Seems like it's going to be beyond my meager Elisp skills to solve. As a workaround , I've found that just doing M-x 'c-mode' in whatever buffer I'm working in allows for the behavior that I'm looking for.